# How to undo changes?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am making an educational game for kids, but I have a big problem. 
This is level one:

```
    <div class="row" id="one">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="img/ananas.png" class="img-responsive dimenzii">
            <h3 class="drop1" id="drop1">______________</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h1 class="green" id="dr2">Кокос</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h1 class="green" id="dr1">Ананас</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="img/coconut.png" class="img-responsive dimenzii">
               <h3 class="drop2" id="drop2">______________</h3>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

I have 4 columns, the outer ones are pictures of fruit, and the two inside contain the name of the fruit so the task is to connect the two. 
It works fine.
The problem is when the game ends, and the question "Do you want to play again?"
appears, if clicked yes, than it shows this first level, but with the names already dragged to the position from before.

I tried to manually change the level to its previous condition but it is not working.
Here is the jquery that I used:

```
    $("#begin,#Yes").click(function(){
    $("#begin").hide();

    game.play();
    points = 0;
    $("#stazi").show();
    $("#final, #one,#two,#three,#four,#five,#six,#seven,#eight").hide();
    $("#one").show();
    $("#poeni").html(points);
    $(".drop1,.drop2").html("_____________");
    $("#dr1,#dr2").show();
    setTimeout( function(){

            game.pause();
            $("#stazi").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#finalPoints").html(points);

            $("#final").delay(1000).fadeIn(2000);
            win.play();

        }
        , 60000 );


});
```

Can anyone tell me how can I save the initial condition so I can use it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save the initial state as a variable before starting. If the levels aren't too big you could use jQuery's [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy it, but don't actually put it in the DOM. When you're ready to reset the game you can use [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to destroy the one on the DOM and replace it with the saved copy of the initial state.

```js
var initialState = $(levelId).clone();

// do stuff that modifies the level

$(levelId).replaceWith(initialState);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot.This worked but only for the view. The design now is the same as the first time the level was played but the functionality is not. 
I'm using the plugins draggable and droppable, and now, after this clone function, when the level starts, there isn't any functionality. 
The page is static. Do you know what is causing it?

Comment: If by functionality you mean events (such as `$("#begin").click(...)`), you could write those in a way that don't attach to the DOM object directly. You could write `$(document).on("click", "#begin", function () { ... })` instead, then anytime a click event is registered on the page it runs if the element being clicked on matches the selector (in this case `#begin`).

Comment: I've tried it and it works for the buttons but what I need it to work for is the droppable function because most of the events are exactly droppable events.. 
I am talking about the default function of the droppable plugin
$("#drop").droppable({.....});
If I change this, then it doesn't work at all.
If I don't change it, then the first time the level is played is okay, the next time, nothing happens.

Comment: Ah. It looks like `clone` has a couple options to clone with events. `.clone(true)` will clone with data and events, and `.clone(true, true)` will do a deep clone with data and events. You could probably just switch to using `.clone(true, true)` for the initial state. If you wanted you could revert back to the old code `.click(...)` instead of `.on("click"...)`, but `on` might have a few advantages, like being a bit less memory intensive (although probably negligible for this project).

Comment: I've been trying that right now, but nothing changes. I've tried it with .clone(true) and .clone(true,true) but nothing is happening.

Comment: I think the problem is this function.

                `$(function() {
        $( "#dr1,#dr2,#dr3,#dr4,#dr5" )
            .draggable({containment:"#wrapper", scroll:false});
    });`

I don't know how to clone this one. 
I tried with $(document).on("load", function()..... but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Spirit_Scarlet I wonder if draggable doesn't clone properly since it's part of jQueryUI. You might need to re-initialize that code after you restore the cloned DOM.